# asssign values to dataframe subset in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having trouble assigning a dataframe to a subset of another. In the example below, the line

`ds[cavities,] <- join(ds[cavities,1:4], fillings, by="ZipCode", "left")`

only modifies one column instead of two. I would expect it either to modify no columns or both, not only one. I wrote the function to fill in the `PrefName` and `CountyID` columns in dataframe `ds` where they are `NA` by joining `ds` to another dataframe `cs`.

As you can see if you run it, the test is failing because `PrefName` is not getting filled in. After doing a bit of debugging, I realized that `join()` is doing exactly what it is expected to do, but the actual *assignment of the result* of that join somehow drops the `PrefName` back to a `NA`.

```
# fully copy-paste-run-able (but broken) code                                                    
suppressMessages({                                                          
    library("plyr")                                                         
    library("methods")                                                      
    library("testthat")                                                     
}) 

# Fill in the missing PrefName/CountyIDs in delstat                         
#   - Find the missing values in Delstat                                    
#   - Grab the CityState Primary Record values                              
#   - Match on zipcode to fill in the holes in the delstat data             
#   - Remove any codes that could not be fixed                              
#   - @param ds: delstat dataframe with 6 columns (see test case)           
#   - @param cs: citystate dataframe with 6 columns (see test case) 
getMissingCounties <- function(ds, cs) {                                    

    if (length(is.na(ds$CountyID))) {                                       

        cavities <- which(is.na(ds$CountyID))                               
        fillings <- cs[cs$PrimRec==TRUE, c(1,3,4)]                          

        ds[cavities,] <- join(ds[cavities,1:4], fillings, by="ZipCode", "left")

        ds <- ds[!is.na(ds$CountyID),]                                      
    }                                                                       

    return(ds)                                                              
}                                                                           
test_getMissingCounties <- function() {                                     

    ds <- data.frame(                                                       
        CityStateKey = c(1,     2,  3,  4  ),                               
        ZipCode      = c(11,    22, 33, 44 ),                               
        Business     = c(1,     1,  1,  1  ),                               
        Residential  = c(1,     1,  1,  1  ),                               
        PrefName     = c("One", NA , NA, NA),                               
        CountyID     = c(111,   NA,  NA, NA))                               

    cs <- data.frame(                                                       
        ZipCode      = c(11,    22,    22,    33,      55    ),             
        Name         = c("eh",  "eh?", "eh?", "eh!?",  "ah." ),             
        PrefName     = c("One", "To",  "Two", "Three", "Five"),             
        CountyID     = c(111,   222,   222,   333,     555   ),             
        PrimRec      = c(TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,    TRUE  ),             
        CityStateKey = c(1,     2,     2,     3,       5     ))             

    expected <- data.frame(                                                 
        CityStateKey = c(1,     2,     3      ),                            
        ZipCode      = c(11,    22,    33     ),                            
        Business     = c(1,     1,     1      ),                            
        Residential  = c(1,     1,     1      ),                            
        PrefName     = c("One", "Two", "Three"),                            
        CountyID     = c(111,   222,   333    ))                            

    expect_equal(getMissingCounties(ds, cs), expected)                      
}

# run the test
test_getMissingCounties()
```

The results are:

```
CityStateKey ZipCode Business Residential PrefName CountyID
       1       11        1          1       One      111
       2       22        1          1      <NA>      222
       3       33        1          1      <NA>      333
```

Any ideas why `PrefName` is getting set to `NA` by the assignment or how to do the assignment so I don't lose data?

Comment: As alluded to in the answer below, the problem is that `ds$PrefName` is a factor with one level, and `cs$PrefName` is a factor with 5 levels. When you try to assign ` ds$PrefName` to the result of the join, the extra levels get set to `NA`. If you add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as the last argument to all of your `data.frame(...)` calls, your code works.

Comment: you need to provide a reproducible example. the current code just produces errors - as expected. how on earth should one know which data set you happen to be interested in? (except if they take the same course, of course, but then chances are that they won't know either).

Comment: @lebatsnok I don't know what you are referring to. course? I'm not in school if that's what you mean. Which dataset I'm interested in? Does it matter? I was asking a question about the behavior of R in this circumstance. The test case is sufficient. If by reproducible you mean code that can show others exactly what the issue is with minimal work on their part, your welcome.

Comment: ok. sorry. my fault, I didn't read your code carefully and saw you provide a just few functions but no data. you're making the dataset within a function... which just makes it less convenient  to find out where the problem is. you just need about half of your code to reproduce the problem. anyway, wish you luck. (but it's probably already there: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`: does this solve your problem?)

Comment: yes, `stringAsFactors=FALSE` solved the problem. @jlhoward, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Why on earth was this question down-voted??!?? The problem here is extremely subtle, and OP clearly put a lot of effort into creating a minimal reproducible example. I wish all the questions on SO were like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can avoid this problem by making sure that there are no factors in your data frames. You do this by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the call(s) to `data.frame(...)`. Note that many of the data import functions, including `read.table(...)` and `read.csv(...)` also convert character to factor by default. You can defeat this behavior the same way.

This problem is actually quite subtle, and is also a good example of how R's "silent coercion" between data types creates all sorts of problems.

The `data.frame(...)` function converts any character vectors to factors by default. So in your code `ds$PerfName` is a factor with one level, and `cs$PerfName` is a factor with 5 levels. So in your assignment statement:

```
ds[cavities,] <- join(ds[cavities,1:4], fillings, by="ZipCode", "left")
```

the 5th column on the LHS is a factor with 1 level, and the 5th column on the RHS is a factor with 5 levels.

***Under some circumstances***, when you assign a factor with more levels to a factor with fewer levels, the missing levels are set to `NA`. Consider this:

```
x <- c("A","B",NA,NA,NA)  # character vector          
y <- LETTERS[1:5]         # character vector
class(x); class(y)
# [1] "character"
# [1] "character"

df <- data.frame(x,y)     # x and y coerced to factor
sapply(df,class)          # df$x and df$y are factors
#        x        y 
# "factor" "factor" 

# assign rows 3:5 of col 2 to col 1
df[3:5,1] <- df[3:5,2]    # fails with a warning
# Warning message:
# In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 3:5) :
#   invalid factor level, NA generated
df                        # missing levels set to NA
#      x y
# 1    A A
# 2    B B
# 3 <NA> C
# 4 <NA> D
# 5 <NA> E
```

The example above is equivalent to your assignment statement. However, notice what happens if you assign *all* of column 2 to column 1.

```
# assign all of col 2 to col 1
df <- data.frame(x,y)
df[,1] <- df[,2]          # succeeds!!
df
#   x y
# 1 A A
# 2 B B
# 3 C C
# 4 D D
# 5 E E
```

This works.

Finally, a note on debugging: if you are debugging a function, sometimes it is useful to run through the statements line by line *at the command line* (e.g., in the global environment). If you did that, you would have gotten the warning above, whereas inside a function call the warnings are suppressed.

Answer (score -1):

The constraints of the test can be satisfied by reimplementing `getMissingCountries` with:

```
merge(ds[1:4], subset(subset(cs, PrimRec)[c(1, 3, 4)]), by="ZipCode")
```

Caveat: the ZipCode column is always emitted first, which differs from your expected result.

But to answer the subassignment question: it breaks, because the level sets of `PrefName` are incompatible between `ds` and `cs`. Either avoid using a factor or `relevel` them. You might have missed R's warning about this, because testthat was somehow suppressing warnings.

Comment: Actually, join() is doing exactly what I want it to. The problem comes when I try to assign it back into the dataframe.

Comment: The issue is that the levels on PrefName in 'ds' do not include those in 'cs', so R is putting NAs there instead. My point was that you don't even need all the 'cavities' stuff, under certain assumptions.